# node_modules installation on external SSD fails with "EPERM" error when installing packages

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, node-modules, solid-state-drive

I'm trying to install Node.js packages on an external SSD connected to my Ubuntu operating system. However, I'm encountering an error during the installation process. Here are the details:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- SSD filesystem: exFAT

Error Message:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../esbuild/bin/esbuild
npm ERR! dest /media/pravin/Samsung_T5/Frontend-practice/manage-landing page/node_modules/.bin/esbuild
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../esbuild/bin/esbuild' -> 
'/media/pravin/Samsung_T5/Frontend-practice/manage-landing- 
 page/node_modules/.bin/esbuild'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../esbuild/bin/esbuild' -> 
'/media/pravin/Samsung_T5/Frontend-practice/manage-landing page/node_modules/.bin/esbuild'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../esbuild/bin/esbuild',
npm ERR!   dest: '/media/pravin/Samsung_T5/Frontend-practice/manage-landing-page/node_modules/.bin/esbuild'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

I'm installing the packages using npm, and it seems to fail when creating a symlink to ../esbuild/bin/esbuild in the destination directory /media/pravin/Samsung_T5/Frontend-practice/manage-landing-page/node_modules/.bin/esbuild.

I have checked the permissions of the file and its containing directories, they appear to be drwxr-xr-x. I tried to change permission with chmod g+w manage-landing-page but it didn't work.

Is there anything specific I should check or any additional steps I need to take in order to install these packages on the external SSD successfully?